# Googlesheets Conditional Formatting Based on Checkbox from another sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, gs-conditional-formatting

I have two sheets and on one I have a checkbox that once it is `TRUE` I want a cell on another sheet to change colour.

I've tried the `INDIRECT` function as part of the "Custom Formula Is", but I just can't get it to work.

```
=indirect("Gina Working!H2")="TRUE"
```

So here, cell H2 on the sheet Gina Working is the cell and sheet that has the checkbox on it.  The Custom Cell Values in Data Validation for the checkbox is set to `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

I just can't see what I'm missing here.
Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Gina Working!H2")=TRUE, 1)
```

Comment: If I may also ask, how do I expand this down my sheet?  For example, GinaH2 when checked formats row 2 on the other sheet, how do I expand that so GinaH3when checked formats the other sheet row3 and so on down my sheet?

Comment: for conditional formatting: `=IF(INDIRECT("Gina Working!H2:H")=TRUE, 1)` ...otherwise: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Gina Working'!H2:H=TRUE, 1, ))`

Comment: As ever, THANK YOU! the conditional formatting code worked perfectly.